# Difference between "have feelings for someone" and "fall in love with someone"

Tags: meaning, difference

Is there any difference between these two phrases? When one says

> I’m having feelings for you

Is it stronger than when one says

> I’m falling in love with you

Comment: We usually say "have feelings **for** you", not "feelings *with* you."  The question is still a good one, though.

Comment: Suggested transfer to English Stack Exchange. As someone who has worked on it for over an hour, I can attest that this question is much, much too complicated for ELL.

Answer (score 2):

"I'm falling in love with you" is generally considered stronger than "I'm having feelings for you"!

Answer (score 0):

We say, "I have feelings for you", and not "I'm having feelings for you".

That said, "I have feelings for you" is milder than "I'm falling in love with you." Someone might well say, "I have feelings for you, but I'm not ready to say that I'm in love with you yet."

By the way, "I'm in love with you" is stronger than "I'm falling in love with you." "I'm falling in love" means you have begun the process toward being in love, but you're not there yet.

Comment: oh is that so?... i did really think that “i’m falling in love” describes the passive status of a person who can’t avoid loving someone. and just can love more.